# pyside2 load qt debug libraries

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyside2

TL;DR:
How can I tell PySide2 to load the Debug libraries of Qt instead of the Release libs (e.g. Load QtCored.dll and not QtCore.dll)

I have a Qt5 C++ application that ships with a Python interpreter that is interpreting PySide2 scripts. When building a release build of my application everything works as expected, e.g.

```
app = QApplication.instance()
```

I receive the QApplication from my C++ application within my Python script.
When doing a debug build in QtCreator I have the problem that QtCreator is loading the debug libraries of Qt whereas PySide2 loads the release libs instead (I can see that with Microsofts Process Explorer). Due to this `QApplication.instance()` returns `None`.

I can't find a way to tell PySide2 to load the debug libraries of Qt, unfortunately. Adjusting `PATH` does not work because Qt installs Debug and Release libs to the same folder.

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but surely it's not enough to build an isolated debug version of Qt? Surely you will need debug versions of Python, PySide2, Qt, etc that are all built against each other?

Comment: If you want PySide2 to run in debug mode then you will have to compile PySide2 with Qt and python in debug mode

Comment: ok that's a massive bummer. I am trying to compile with 'python setup.py build --qmake=... --debug' but I am getting complains about missing Clang compiler. VS2017 community seems to miss the option to install clang for windows - frustrating